# Laravel/Mysql, problem with user/favourite table

Tags: sql, laravel

Have favorite table (Laravel/MySql) with  id, users_id, firm_id.
I want that one user can make one firm favorite, and remove it (favorite). I make that things works in some way, my problem is when one user make one firm favorite, next user when log in he doesn't have option to make this same firm as favorited, he can just unfavorite it.
It is little confusing, hope that you will understand, and help me.

**Controller**

```
class favourite_controller extends Controller
{
    
    public function save_firm_favourite($firm_id){
        
        $user_id = auth::id();
      

        $save_favourite = new favourite;
        $save_favourite->user_id = $user_id;
        $save_favourite->firm_id = $firm_id;
        $save_favourite->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success' , 'Uspješno spremljeno u favorite');
        
    }

    public function remove_firm_favourite($firm_id){
        
        $remove_from_favourites = favourite::where('firm_id' , $firm_id);
        $remove_from_favourites->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success' , 'Uspješno uklonjeno iz favorita');
        
    }

}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/save_to_favourites/{firm_id}' , 'favourite_controller@save_firm_favourite')->name('save_user_firm_favourite');
Route::get('/remove_from_favourites/{firm_id}' , 'favourite_controller@remove_firm_favourite')->name('remove_firm_favourite');
```

**SQL**

```
id
user_id
firm_id
created_at
updated_at
```

Comment: Can you post your related view file(s?)

Answer (score 0):

Thx at interest, but I done it, i just needed to do simple query at DB, this query was like filter

```
   $user_id = auth::id();




    $show_fav_buttton = 0;
    $show_remove_fav_button = 1;

    $favourite_check =  DB::table('favourites')->where('user_id' , '=' , $user_id)->where('firm_id' , '=' , $id)->first();

    if(!$favourite_check){
        return view('opg')->with('my_opg' , $find_opg)
    ->with('favourite_check_show_fav_button' ,  $show_fav_buttton);

    }else{
        return view('opg')->with('my_opg' , $find_opg)
    ->with('favourite_check_show_remove_button' , $show_remove_fav_button );
    }
```